# Не работает подзапрос в MYSQL з кондишеном IN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-5.7

Єсть запрос который должен получить все идентификаторы продукта на сайте по группе в 1с, таблица з группой имеет родителя и свой ид, екей категория родитель - ребенок, так вот, группу можно указать любого уровня вложенности и она у нее не ограниченная, но продукт зачастую крепится к последнему ребенку данной группы, под запрос же вытягивает id всех детей указанной группы, но вот проблема в том что по отдельности под запрос работает, и идентификаторы возвращает верные, но почему-то главный запрос не ведёт то что он возвращает, где может быть причина

```
SELECT `p`.`product_id` as `id`, 22 AS value
FROM `onec_product_groups_products` AS `p`
WHERE `onec_product_group_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM 
                                   (SELECT id, parent_id FROM onec_product_groups ORDER BY parent_id, id) ocpg,
                                   (SELECT @pv := '0453c8f1-6336-11e8-80cb-002590dbae45') initialisation
                                 WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)));
```

Ещё вижу что если я использую IDE для запросов то она возвращает данную ошибку

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'find_in_set'
```

но в IDE запрос по раздельности на вытях идентификаторов категории не работает, проверял в phpmyadmin, то все хорошо. Не знаю достаточно ли информации я предоставил, если нет напишите, пожалуйста, в комменты, буду исправлять.

### Update

Заметил что если не использовать `IN`, а связаться с группой напрямую по жёсткой связи через INNER JOIN то все работает гуд:

```
SELECT `p`.`product_id` as `id`, 22 AS value
 FROM `onec_product_groups_products` AS `p`
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `id` FROM 
                                   (SELECT id, parent_id FROM onec_product_groups ORDER BY parent_id, id) ocpg,
                                   (SELECT @pv := '0453c8f1-6336-11e8-80cb-002590dbae45') initialisation
                                 where find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)))
 AS groups ON groups.id=p.onec_product_group_id;
```

По сути данное решения решает мою проблему, но я не пойму, все равно проблема с `IN` останется и я бы хотел знать что не так и где я нарушаю принципы

Comment: Ошибка - в местоположении `ORDER BY parent_id, id`. Он должен быть не в подзапросе `ocpg`, а в подзапросе, который используется в IN. Запомните - сортировка внутри подзапроса (в данном случае - `ocpg`) игнорируется во внешних запросах.

Comment: Но у мене не получиться вынести сортировку, и разве сортировка не работает относительно под запроса, плюс обновил описание заметил как можно обойти данную проблему з IN, что доказывает что под запрос работает нормально

Comment: *разве сортировка не работает относительно под запроса* Внутри - работает. Как только вышел наружу - игнорируется, и в любой момент может потеряться. *заметил как можно обойти данную проблему з IN, что доказывает что под запрос работает нормально* Это - случайность. Везение. Однажды оно кончится, и неожиданно ранее работавший правильно запрос вернёт ерунду. Нет, если тебя это устраивает - то ради бога, мне-то пофиг...

Comment: @Akina нет ну если это везения, то в данном случае исправьте меня как будет верно, я же не говорил что это истина в последней инстанции, я увидел что данный момент решает проблему, если это костыль, то прошу поправьте меня, я же написал в вопросе если данных не достаточно то я постараюсь предоставить больше информации, если же как вы написали проблема в `ORDER BY` то напишите как будет верно з учётом поставленной задачи.

Comment: Всё, что не задано явно, может быть как угодно. Сервер имеет право обрабатывать набор записей, полученный из таблицы или подзапроса, в том порядке, в каком посчитает нужным - в том числе не совпадающем с тем порядком, в каком записи расположены в этом наборе. Именно поэтому порядок обработки записей в любой момент МОЖЕТ измениться (а может и не измениться) - т.е. результат МОЖЕТ быть верным, а может и не быть. И главное - это совершенно непредсказуемо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть вот так:

```sql
SELECT `p`.`product_id` as `id`, 22 AS value
FROM `onec_product_groups_products` AS `p`
INNER JOIN ( SELECT `id` 
             FROM onec_product_groups ocpg
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT @pv := '0453c8f1-6336-11e8-80cb-002590dbae45' pv) init
             WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) 
               AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
             ORDER BY parent_id, id ) AS groups ON groups.id=p.onec_product_group_id;
```

В таком случае сортировка обеспечивает правильную последовательность обработки записей именно в подзапросе `groups`.

Возможно, даже сортировку надо расширить до `ORDER BY parent_id = pv DESC, parent_id, id` - чтобы гарантировать, что запись с заданным исходным GUID будет обработана первой.

Comment: с `ORDER BY parent_id = pv DESC, parent_id, id` количество записей отличается, не знаю в лучшую ли это сторону

Comment: @UKRman Неверная постановка. Либо в том, либо в другом, либо в обоих случаях результат - неверный. Вы бы создали fiddle со своими структурами и примером данных - тогда можно было бы посмотреть на результат не в теории, а предметно. На самом деле предположу, что в обоих случаях результат неверный - он может быть верным только в случае, если в таблице есть `CHECK (parent_id < id)`.

Comment: заведу пример таблиц в песочнице.

Comment: @UKRman Воспользуйтесь https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7